# Create list of agents in Anylogic that meet a criteria

Tags: anylogic

Here is a model I am working on, where I am trying to create a list of agents from a population that meets the criteria.

```
traceln(filter( main.facilities, p -> p.WasteAvlty == 1 ));
```

The returned list is as follows,

[image]

But I want a list with the index number of the agent, and not the name of the agent. As my objective, is to create a list of agent index that meet the criteria.

The returned list should be like {0,1,2,3} and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList <Integer> theList=new ArrayList();
List <Facility> facilities=filter( main.facilities, p -> p.WasteAvlty == 1 );
for(Facility f : facilities){
     theList.add(f.getIndex());
}
```

Or

```
List <Facility> facilities=filter( main.facilities, p -> p.WasteAvlty == 1 );
int [] theList=new int[facilities.size()];
int i=0;
for(Facility f : facilities){
         theList[i]=f.getIndex();
         i++;
    }
```

Comment: Description: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Integer> to int[]. Location: Traveling Salesman/Order/buildRandOrder - Function

I have a parameter called destination which is of type Other> int[]

How can I convert this array list to a java list?

Comment: I found a way to convert the Integer list to int[] list using,

 {
  int[] ret = new int[theList.size()];
  for(int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
    ret[i] = theList.get(i);
  
  return ret;
}

But is there a better way?